# Removing noise from signal? (correlated noise and any function)

Tags: regression, signal-processing, regression-analysis

I am trying to find any type of function that will allow me to discern between the function and correlated noise.

I can only think of examples that don't work, like:

```
ug=matrix(nrow=N,c(0.5,0.4,0.4,0.5))
d=matrix(nrow = 500,ncol = 2)
noise=mvrnorm(n=500,rep(0,N),ug)
d[,1]=noise[,1]
d[,2]=sin(d[m,1])+noise[,2]
plot(d[,1],d[,2])
points(d[,1],sin(d[,1]),col="red")
```

The above gives me this:

[image]

So, whenever I try to apply any regression, I end up getting independent results because the regression captures both the noise and the sin() ending up with something like:
[image]

Is there any function I could use where I can discern using a regression between the function and the correlated noise? (I guess it should be some sort of regression that captures the signal and not the errors?)

Comment: This looks like you are overfitting. Try your regression with fewer parameters.

Comment: I see, but even If I make it smoother, I wouldn't be able to separeate the function from the noise... Any regression I has used removes both the function and the noise...

Comment: Well, I am not sure what you objective is - if you are just trying to get it right for this example where you know the true correlation. If so, your estimation should take that correlation into account. I don't know if you are using OLS above, but if you are, there are implicit assumptions regarding no correlation of the error term in OLS, which would be violated here. So the solution would be to take the correlation structure into account.